# How check element was painted on display

Tags: cocos2d-x

Is it possible check element was painted(rendered) on display?

Because node can not be null and isVisible true, but element is not presented on screen like image. I means loading period for example, when element created and init() but not rendered yet on screen.

A lot of thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are developing on xcode, you can try to capture a openGL frame, and see how it paints your object

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/ToolsOverview/ToolsOverview.html